# iOS: Make json data from one section available in another

Tags: ios, objective-c

I took a bit of a break from iOS programming for a couple of versions and now I'm feeling a bit rusty.  What I want to do is quite simple. I've got some Json data that's loaded in one section of my app that appears to be unavailable in another. And I can't quite figure out how to get it to work.

Section 1

```
- (void)addSpringBroadIcon
{
    primeView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.bounds.size.width, self.view.bounds.size.height)];



    primeShadowView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.bounds.size.width, self.view.bounds.size.height)];
    [primeShadowView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
    [self.view addSubview:primeShadowView];
    [primeShadowView setHidden:YES];

SESpringBoard *board2 = [SESpringBoard initWithTitle:@"Welcome" items:items launcherImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"navbtn_home.png"]];

[primeView addSubview:board2];
    [self.view addSubview:primeView];
```

Section 2

```
- (void)fetchedData:(NSData *)responseData
{
NSMutableArray *items = [NSMutableArray array];
            for (NSDictionary *dict in pJson) {
                [items addObject:[SEMenuItem initWithTitle:[dict objectForKey:@"name"] imageName:@"vitamin_d.jpg" viewController:self removable:NO]];
}
}
```

**UPDATE**

Section 2(revised)

```
    - (void)fetchedData:(NSData *)responseData
    {
if(responsePlaceData)
    {
        NSString *json = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:responseData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
        NSString *aesResponse = [AES256Util decWithString:json key:aeskey];
        //NSLog(@"AES:%@",aesResponse);
        NSData* jsonResponse = [aesResponse dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
        NSDictionary* placeJson = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:jsonResponse options:kNilOptions error:nil];
        page = [[placeJson objectForKey:@"page"] intValue];
        NSLog(@"%d",page);
        if (page > 0) {
            NSDictionary* pJson = [placeJson objectForKey:@"data"];
            self.items = [NSMutableArray array];
            for (NSDictionary *dict in pJson) {
               [self.items addObject:[SEMenuItem initWithTitle:[dict objectForKey:@"name"] imageName:[dict objectForKey:@"image"] viewController:self removable:NO]];


                }
```

Update: My thinking is that the data from self.items in section 2 should be available, already decrypted, in section 1.

Basically I just want to make the *items in "fetchedData" available to *board2 in the "addSpringBoardIcon" section. I tried just reversing the order of the sections,but obviously that didn't work.  Maybe changing the viewController target?  I dunno.

I also tried various ways of getting the data to load IN addSpringBoardIcon... none of those works. I can get all the data to load in the fetchedData section (incl. making the items work with *board2), but that messes up the view.

Any ideas (or if you need me to clear up anything because the way I explained it is kind of a mess) would be appreciated.

Comment: No idea what you mean by "section". That would typically mean "section in a table view" but it doesn't look like that's what you're doing here. Do you mean "I want to share the same data across different view controllers"?

Comment: Strangely enough... I mean exactly what I said (even if that might not make much sense.) Put it like this: I've got a ViewController.m I want to load "responseData" from some json. By "section" I mean the -(void)SectionNameHere. So all the decrypted data is available in -(void)responseData... but not in the -(void)addSpringBoard section. That's my best shot at explaining it. I want to load j-son data that loads fine in the responseData section but doesn't load at all in the addSpringBoard section. If it still doesn't make sense just let me know and I'll delete the question and figure it out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer based on what you said in the comments - it sounds like you're just working with one View Controller here. Your items Array is a local variable, which means it is only available within the scope of your fetchedData: method.

You need to have a variable scoped to the whole class - that is, an instance variable. The best way to do this in Objective-C is using a [property](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ProgrammingWithObjectiveC/EncapsulatingData/EncapsulatingData.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011210-CH5-SW2).

How do you create the property then? Probably like this, at the top of your implementation file.

```
@interface MyViewController()
@property NSMutableArray *items;
@end

@implementation MyViewController
// the rest of your code...
```

Then when you want to access it in code later, you'd do that using self.

```
- (void)fetchedData:(NSData *)responseData
{
   self.items = [NSMutableArray array];
```

Comment: Close... but no. It still only works locally.  when I run an NSLog(@"uru:%@",self.items); it displays the info in the fetched data method... but still not in the addSpringBoard method. There it just returns null like it always did. The problem is that I want to access the response data... well... data in AddSpringBoard. And it still isn't working. I set it up exactly as you suggested.

Comment: Add more code to your question, like the whole class.

Comment: That would be complicated, but I posted the complete code (or most of it) from section 2. There's AES encryption which is decrypted there... but my thinking is that self.items should be available throughout the file right?

Comment: How are you using items in the addSpringBoard method?

Comment: SESpringBoard *board2 = [SESpringBoard initWithTitle:@"Welcome" items:self.items launcherImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"navbtn_home.png"]];

Comment: Maybe we can start a chat room and I can show you the actual file?